# I have a json with repeated parent objects. I need to merge all childs under one parent using jq in bash

Tags: json, jq

I have a json with repeated parent objects. I need to merge all childs under one parent using jq in bash. Below is the json array. Below source one's are parents. I need to take a single parent item and merge it with all child items. Is it possible with jq?

```
 [
        {
            "source": null,
            "target": {
                "id": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": 1
            },
            "target": {
                "id": 2
            }
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": 1
            },
            "target": {
                "id": 3
            }
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": 1
            },
            "target": {
                "id": 10
            }
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": 1
            },
            "target": {
                "id": 11
            }
        }
    ]
```

Expected output:-

```
 [
        {
            "source": null,
            "target": {
                "id": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": 1
            },
            "target-1": {
                "id": 2
            },
            "target-2": {
                "id": 3
            },
            "target-3": {
                "id": 10
            },
            "target-4": {
                "id": 11
            }
        }
    ]
```

Comment: This would be a fair bit easier if you wanted `{"source-null": [1], "source-1": [1, 2, 3, 10, 11]}` as your output. Is there a reason for the format chosen?

Comment: Also, why just `"target"` and not `"target-1"` as the identifier of the first target for `"source": null`?

Comment: [{"source": [1]}, {"source":1, "target": [ 2, 3, 10, 11]}}] This is also fine. I have to make api request with those id's and have to show the result of source id as parent and target id's as it childs.

Comment: Err, you mean `[{"source": null, "target": [1]}, {"source": 1, "target": [2,3,10,11]}]`, surely?

Comment: I guess I can loop through those id's with  `cat stack.json | jq .[1].target[2]` and make api calls.

Comment: I don't understand why you'd need to, but then, you haven't shared your API.

Comment: And btw, in general, _never_ run `cat somefile | ...`; it's more efficient to run `... <somefile` (or its equivalent `<somefile ...`), which gives the program `...` a direct file handle on `somefile`, instead of giving it only a FIFO to read with the output from the separate executable `cat` (which is not part of the shell). FIFOs are less flexible -- they aren't seekable, and can only be read once front-to-back, so programs that might otherwise want to parallelize or know the total input size up front (or just skip to the end of input) can't do that when they're only given a FIFO.

Comment: It is the requirement and api is internal thing. About cat.... just for understanding i used. Normally `jq .[1].target[2] stack.json` this is how I will use.

Comment: You're probably looking for something like this https://jqplay.org/s/i-KJ7v2ee-

Comment: @oguzismail exactly. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jq` has a handy group-by operator.

Since you've made it clear [in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65307236/i-have-a-json-with-repeated-parent-objects-i-need-to-merge-all-childs-under-one/65307722#comment115456488_65307236) that the goal of this question is to know how to perform grouping, and the exact output format is secondary, an example of such grouping would be:

```
jq 'group_by(.source?.id // "") | [.[] | {"\(.[0].source?.id)": [.[].target.id]}] | add'
```

...generating output (for your given input) of:

```json
{
  "1": [
    2,
    3,
    10,
    11
  ],
  "null": [
    1
  ]
}
```

Comment: Output is not array, there will be multiple parents and childs and `,` are missing between objects. Directly number as json key is coming which is hard to track through automation.  Thanks for the quick response. I will work it out from here.